# Ribbon of mean plus/minus sd behind boxplots when x value is a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot boxplots for several categories and I found very handy if there is a ribbon showing the mean +/- standard deviation for the whole dataset.

I can easily get those values and put them in the plot using the `geom_hline()` function, however, I want the area between `mean(x) + sd(x)` and `mean(x) - sd(x)` to be coloured for better visibility. I was thinking adding `geom_ribbon()`there, however I crashed into a problem that my values a cathegorical and I want those lines to fully cover the background on x axis.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(
  a = rnorm(1000, 20, 40),
  b = rnorm(1000, 100, 40)
)
df
df <- melt(df)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(
    mean(df$value) - sd(df$value),
    mean(df$value) + sd(df$value)
  )) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(df$value), size = 3, col = "red") +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed. I only did not find the right keywords.

Comment: Or actually no, the difference is that I am working with discrete values on x axis and the question on given link works with continous.

Comment: No worries, closed as duplicate. Duplicates are useful for future users with different keywords.

Comment: The idea is to use geom_rect, then it is a dupe. Feel free to vote re-open, of course.

Comment: Ok. But is `geom_rect()` applicable this way if the x axis is discrete?

Comment: If you have a question where solutions depend on the data type, it's important to replicate that in your example. You also might be mixing up your x and y axes in describing them: you're saying but what if x is discrete, but the x you've shown here *is* discrete

Answer (score 1):

Try using *geom_rect*:

```
ggplot(df, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf , 
                xmax = Inf ,
                ymin = mean(df$value) - sd(df$value) ,
                ymax = mean(df$value) + sd(df$value) ,
                fill = "blue")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(df$value), size = 3, col = "red") +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but somehow this script does not work to me. The given error says that "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale", which is true. Or is -Inf and Inf recognized also in discrete scales?